# Windows agent connection unstable on jenkins

Tags: java, windows, jenkins

Multiple windows agents configured as slaves on jenkins. Our windows agents disconnect frequently with below errors. We are using websocket for connection.

Details:

Jenkins v2.263 and Windows server 2016 / 2012 R2 / 2019

Error logs on agent side

```
Oct 01, 2021 7:46:45 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main createEngine
INFO: Setting up agent: jwinslave001
Oct 01, 2021 7:46:45 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener <init>
INFO: Jenkins agent is running in headless mode.
Oct 01, 2021 7:46:45 AM hudson.remoting.Engine startEngine
INFO: Using Remoting version: 4.5
Oct 01, 2021 7:46:45 AM org.jenkinsci.remoting.engine.WorkDirManager initializeWorkDir
INFO: Using C:\jwinslave001-slave\remoting as a remoting work directory
Oct 01, 2021 7:47:06 AM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: Connection failed.
io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Connection failed.
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer$1.call(JdkClientContainer.java:200)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer$1.call(JdkClientContainer.java:126)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer.openClientSocket(JdkClientContainer.java:205)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:663)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:712)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:866)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(Unknown Source)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:511)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:355)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.runWebSocket(Engine.java:628)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:470)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The semaphore timeout period has expired.

    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.translateErrorToIOException(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.access$700(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.AsynchronousChannelGroupImpl$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Also, below logs when a test job was configured to run on windows slave. the test job ran for about a day then the agent disconnected with below error ..

```
Sep 28, 2021 10:22:13 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Read side closed
Sep 28, 2021 10:22:14 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener status
INFO: Terminated
Sep 28, 2021 10:22:35 PM hudson.remoting.jnlp.Main$CuiListener error
SEVERE: Connection failed.
io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Connection failed.
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer$1.call(JdkClientContainer.java:200)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer$1.call(JdkClientContainer.java:126)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.container.jdk.client.JdkClientContainer.openClientSocket(JdkClientContainer.java:205)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:663)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:712)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:866)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:511)
    at io.jenkins.remoting.shaded.org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:355)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.runWebSocket(Engine.java:628)
    at hudson.remoting.Engine.run(Engine.java:470)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The semaphore timeout period has expired.

    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.translateErrorToIOException(Iocp.java:309)
    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp.access$700(Iocp.java:46)
    at sun.nio.ch.Iocp$EventHandlerTask.run(Iocp.java:399)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Logs seen on jenkins ..

```
2021-09-20 17:35:43.962+0000 [id=24231] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-24231 for jwinslave0037 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 17:42:23.510+0000 [id=24231] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-24231 for jwinslave0037 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 18:04:39.918+0000 [id=46158] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46158 for jwinslave0037 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 18:04:39.921+0000 [id=46642] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46642 for jwinslave0037 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 18:15:14.245+0000 [id=46498] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46498 for jwinslave0049 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 18:15:44.682+0000 [id=46503] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46503 for jwinslave0051 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 18:35:45.473+0000 [id=46503] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46503 for jwinslave0055 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException


2021-09-20 18:35:45.471+0000 [id=27959] INFO    hudson.slaves.ChannelPinger$1#onDead: Ping failed. Terminating the channel jwinslave0055.
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Ping started at 1632162705470 hasn't completed by 1632162945471
        at hudson.remoting.PingThread.ping(PingThread.java:134)
        at hudson.remoting.PingThread.run(PingThread.java:90)
2021-09-20 18:35:45.473+0000 [id=46503] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46503 for jwinslave0055 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

2021-09-20 18:45:16.789+0000 [id=46503] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46503 for jwinslave0056 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

2021-09-20 18:56:30.353+0000 [id=46498] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46498 for jwinslave0058 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException

2021-09-20 18:59:46.368+0000 [id=46971] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46971 for jwinslave0058 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 19:54:02.241+0000 [id=47687] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-47687 for jwinslave0049 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 19:54:02.241+0000 [id=43]    WARNING n.b.j.internal.common.JavaLogger#warn: exception while collecting data
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at jenkins.agents.WebSocketAgents$Session.closed(WebSocketAgents.java:141)
        at jenkins.websocket.WebSocketSession.onWebSocketSomething(WebSocketSession.java:91)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.onWebSocketClose(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onClose(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.callApplicationOnClose(WebSocketSession.java:394)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.disconnect(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:316)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.DisconnectCallback.succeeded(DisconnectCallback.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection$CallbackBridge.writeSuccess(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.notifyCallbackSuccess(FrameFlusher.java:359)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.succeedEntries(FrameFlusher.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.succeeded(FrameFlusher.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.flush(FrameFlusher.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.process(FrameFlusher.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.outgoingFrame(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.close(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:510)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@3cce4ea7:jwinslave0032": Remote call on jwinslave0032 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.callAsync(Channel.java:1029)
        at net.bull.javamelody.RemoteCallHelper.collectDataByNodeName(RemoteCallHelper.java:188)
        at net.bull.javamelody.RemoteCallHelper.collectJavaInformationsListByName(RemoteCallHelper.java:213)
        at net.bull.javamelody.NodesCollector.collectWithoutErrorsNow(NodesCollector.java:159)
        at net.bull.javamelody.NodesCollector.collectWithoutErrors(NodesCollector.java:147)
        at net.bull.javamelody.NodesCollector$2.run(NodesCollector.java:115)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2021-09-20 19:54:02.243+0000 [id=47687] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-47687 for jwinslave0043 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 19:54:02.243+0000 [id=47687] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-47687 for jwinslave0043 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 19:54:02.246+0000 [id=43]    WARNING n.b.j.internal.common.JavaLogger#warn: exception while collecting data
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at jenkins.agents.WebSocketAgents$Session.closed(WebSocketAgents.java:141)
        at jenkins.websocket.WebSocketSession.onWebSocketSomething(WebSocketSession.java:91)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.onWebSocketClose(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onClose(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.callApplicationOnClose(WebSocketSession.java:394)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.disconnect(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:316)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.DisconnectCallback.succeeded(DisconnectCallback.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection$CallbackBridge.writeSuccess(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.notifyCallbackSuccess(FrameFlusher.java:359)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.succeedEntries(FrameFlusher.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.succeeded(FrameFlusher.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.flush(FrameFlusher.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.process(FrameFlusher.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.outgoingFrame(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.close(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:510)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@3cce4ea7:jwinslave0032": Remote call on jwinslave0032 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.callAsync(Channel.java:1029)
        at net.bull.javamelody.RemoteCallHelper.collectDataByNodeName(RemoteCallHelper.java:188)
        at net.bull.javamelody.RemoteCallHelper.collectJavaInformationsListByName(RemoteCallHelper.java:213)
        at net.bull.javamelody.NodesCollector.collectWithoutErrorsNow(NodesCollector.java:159)
        at net.bull.javamelody.NodesCollector.collectWithoutErrors(NodesCollector.java:147)
        at net.bull.javamelody.NodesCollector$2.run(NodesCollector.java:115)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2021-09-20 19:54:02.254+0000 [id=46158] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46158 for jwinslave0032 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 19:54:02.255+0000 [id=47687] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-47687 for jwinslave0051 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 19:54:02.262+0000 [id=46642] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46642 for jwinslave0055 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 19:54:03.020+0000 [id=46158] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46158 for jwinslave0036 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 19:54:03.022+0000 [id=46328] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46328 for jwinslave0056 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 19:54:03.158+0000 [id=46503] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46503 for jwinslave0058 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 19:54:03.159+0000 [id=46158] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46158 for jwinslave0037 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-20 19:54:03.159+0000 [id=43]    WARNING n.b.j.internal.common.JavaLogger#warn: exception while collecting data
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at jenkins.agents.WebSocketAgents$Session.closed(WebSocketAgents.java:141)
        at jenkins.websocket.WebSocketSession.onWebSocketSomething(WebSocketSession.java:91)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.onWebSocketClose(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onClose(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.callApplicationOnClose(WebSocketSession.java:394)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.disconnect(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:316)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.DisconnectCallback.succeeded(DisconnectCallback.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection$CallbackBridge.writeSuccess(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.notifyCallbackSuccess(FrameFlusher.java:359)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.succeedEntries(FrameFlusher.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.succeeded(FrameFlusher.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.flush(FrameFlusher.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.process(FrameFlusher.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.outgoingFrame(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.close(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:510)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@7288d1eb:jwinslave0037": Remote call on jwinslave0037 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.callAsync(Channel.java:1029)
        at net.bull.javamelody.RemoteCallHelper.collectDataByNodeName(RemoteCallHelper.java:188)
        at net.bull.javamelody.RemoteCallHelper.collectJavaInformationsListByName(RemoteCallHelper.java:213)
        at net.bull.javamelody.NodesCollector.collectWithoutErrorsNow(NodesCollector.java:159)
        at net.bull.javamelody.NodesCollector.collectWithoutErrors(NodesCollector.java:147)
        at net.bull.javamelody.NodesCollector$2.run(NodesCollector.java:115)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
2021-09-21 11:55:32.504+0000 [id=46158] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46158 for jwinslave0036 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-21 11:55:33.256+0000 [id=46158] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46158 for jwinslave0037 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-21 11:55:33.403+0000 [id=47687] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-47687 for jwinslave0051 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-21 11:55:33.403+0000 [id=46498] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46498 for jwinslave0058 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-21 11:55:33.406+0000 [id=46328] INFO    j.s.DefaultJnlpSlaveReceiver#channelClosed: Jetty (winstone)-46328 for jwinslave0056 terminated: java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
2021-09-21 11:55:33.405+0000 [id=43]    WARNING n.b.j.internal.common.JavaLogger#warn: exception while collecting data
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
        at jenkins.agents.WebSocketAgents$Session.closed(WebSocketAgents.java:141)
        at jenkins.websocket.WebSocketSession.onWebSocketSomething(WebSocketSession.java:91)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy126.onWebSocketClose(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.JettyListenerEventDriver.onClose(JettyListenerEventDriver.java:149)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession.callApplicationOnClose(WebSocketSession.java:394)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.disconnect(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:316)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.DisconnectCallback.succeeded(DisconnectCallback.java:42)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection$CallbackBridge.writeSuccess(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:86)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.notifyCallbackSuccess(FrameFlusher.java:359)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.succeedEntries(FrameFlusher.java:288)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.succeeded(FrameFlusher.java:280)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.WriteFlusher.write(WriteFlusher.java:293)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractEndPoint.write(AbstractEndPoint.java:381)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.flush(FrameFlusher.java:264)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.FrameFlusher.process(FrameFlusher.java:193)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.processing(IteratingCallback.java:241)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.IteratingCallback.iterate(IteratingCallback.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.outgoingFrame(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:581)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.close(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:181)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:510)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.io.AbstractWebSocketConnection.onFillable(AbstractWebSocketConnection.java:440)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:311)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:105)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$1.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:104)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:336)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:313)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:171)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:129)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:375)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:773)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:905)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused: hudson.remoting.ChannelClosedException: Channel "hudson.remoting.Channel@4a56294d:jwinslave0056": Remote call on jwinslave0056 failed. The channel is closing down or has closed down
        at hudson.remoting.Channel.callAsync(Channel.java:1029)
        at net.bull.javamelody.RemoteCallHelper.collectDataByNodeName(RemoteCallHelper.java:188)
        at net.bull.javamelody.RemoteCallHelper.collectJavaInformationsListByName(RemoteCallHelper.java:213)
        at net.bull.javamelody.NodesCollector.collectWithoutErrorsNow(NodesCollector.java:159)
        at net.bull.javamelody.NodesCollector.collectWithoutErrors(NodesCollector.java:147)
        at net.bull.javamelody.NodesCollector$2.run(NodesCollector.java:115)
        at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
        at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

We have configured a batch script on windows and created a task in task scheduler on windows server for the connection to be Up always. Another issue seen is the task goes from running to ready state sometimes. Sometimes even if the task is running the agent is still disconnected.